# Bind the ip adresses with the hosts using socat command

Tags: proxy, squid, socat

I have **squid** proxy installed in my server, and I want to bind the ip adresses with the hosts I want to connect to them.

How can I do it with socat command?

**Example :**

```
prox_IP : 1.1.1.1
proxy_port : 1111

host_to_connect: 2.2.2.2
port_to connect: 2222
```

How can I connect to `2.2.2.2:2222` connect like my address IP is `1.1.1.1:1111`?